# Double binding: Model <-> Bean <-> JavaFX

Tags: data-binding, javafx

Considering I have the following three classes:

Model:

```
class Field {
    private String label;
}
```

Bean:

```
class FieldBean {
    public FieldBean(Field f) { this.field = f};
    private Field field;
    private SimpleStringProperty label = new SimpleStringProperty();
    public String getLabel() { return label.get(); }
}
```

JavaFX Application:

```
class MyApp extends Application {
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Label lblTest = new Label();
        FieldBean fieldBean = new FieldBean(model.getField());
        Bindings.bindBidirectional(fieldBean.getLabel(), label.textProperty());
    }
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is to have the Label updated, whenever i change the Field label. From what I know of this model binding so far, I need to add a PropertyChangeListener, but I haven't got a clue, where about it should be attached.  My guess would be in the FieldBean. (and my model already has property change support, just stripped it for better readability).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `JavaBeanStringProperty`, which is basically an adapter between a JavaFX `StringProperty` and a bound JavaBeans property. For example:

```
class FieldBean {

    private final StringProperty label ;
    private final Field field;

    public FieldBean(Field f) { 
        this.field = f;
        label = JavaBeanStringPropertyBuilder.create()
            .bean(this.field)
            .name(label)
            .build();
    public String getLabel() { return label.get(); }
    public StringProperty labelProperty() { return label ; }
    public void setLabel(String label) { this.label.set(label); }
}
```

then (assuming you have property change listeners set up for `Field.label`), `Field.label` and `FieldBean.label` will automatically be bound.

As Tomas points out, you don't need both of these classes as they effectively represent exactly the same thing. You can omit the `Field` class as Tomas shows, or, if your `Field` class already exists as part of a data representation that's already written, you can just use the `JavaBeanStringProperty` as an adapter to bind directly to a bound JavaBean property:

```
Field field = new Field();

// ...

Label uiLabel = new Label();
uiLabel.textProperty().bind(JavaBeanStringPropertyBuilder.create()
    .bean(field)
    .name(label)
    .build());
```

Calling `field.setLabel(...)` now automatically changes `uiLabel`'s text. In this example the `FieldBean` class is omitted entirely.

Answer (score 0):

If `FieldBean.field.label` and `FieldBean.label.get()` are meant to represent the same value, then there is no need to have them both.

```
class FieldBean {
    private StringProperty label;

    public FieldBean(String label) {
        this.label = new SimpleStringProperty(label);
    }

    public StringProperty labelProperty() { return label; }
    public String getLabel() { return label.get(); }
}
```

Then, to keep a `Label` updated, you just do

```
label.textProperty().bind(fieldBean.labelProperty());
```

Notice that the class `Field` is omitted altogether.